# c++ managed code

Tags: c++

```
1 #include"unmanaged.h"
2 #include"stdafx.h"
3 using namespace std;
4 _gc class Mclass
5 {
6 private:
7 string Mx;
8 cppclass * obj;
9 public:
10 Mclass();
11 ~Mclass();
12  string native();
13 };
```

when buliding this throws

error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed.

Note: C++ does not support default-int and

error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '

the content of unmanged.h is

```
#include"stdafx.h"
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class cppclass
{
private:
string x;
public:
cppclass();
~cppclass();
string native();
};
```

Comment: Please format your code and show the line numbers of the errors.

Comment: You need two underscores in `__gc`.

Comment: @ManuDilipShah Don't forget to select Mankarse's answer if it solved your problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two underscores in `__gc`. See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712825%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).